# Hermeneutics on Christianity

Tags: discussion

In case anybody wasn't aware, can I draw everyone's attention to [this question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/958/should-we-be-migrating-more-questions-to-biblical-hermeneutics). It's about how Hermeneutics questions should be treated on Christianity SE.